# CSS float right issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am into designing my page and I've got troubled aligning the header.
As you can see here:

[image]

I wanted the "Add" will  align with the employee list. How would I do that?

By the way here's the html code:
I've used **bootstrap**. But a native css suggestion is still good.

```
    <div class="title">
                <h4>Employee list</h4> 
                <span class="pull-right">Add</span>
            </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the `Add` to before the `<h4>`. When you float right, the target element should be before the other element if you want them to align.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ar7G6/)

HTML

```
<div class="title">
     <span class="pull-right">Add</span>
     <h4>Employee list</h4> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.pull-right {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I never thought it was this simple.. LoL. By the way, why is it that if I put it at the bottom of h4 it drops down?

Comment: It's because the h4 is a block level element, so it takes up 100% of the width. When you put the span below it, it will always display below the h4, even when floated.

Answer (score 0):

give h4 width auto and float left

CSS

```
h4
{ 
float:left;width:auto
 }
```

and span float right width auto

```
.pull-right
{
 float:right;width:auto
}
```